# bash: why use "treat all files as text" flag with the diff command?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, diff, command-line-arguments

I see a few examples when using the diff command, particularly using it recursively for checking whole directories, to use "diff -ar foo/ foo2/".

If I'm checking a bunch of mixed files (some text, some binary) it seems to go against the grain to treat all files as text, even though it works!

Is it really a good idea to use -a when checking directories containing binaries? If so, could anyone explain why?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your use case, really.  The "binary files are different" output is usually more useful than seeing the precise difference, but sometimes you do want the exact, precise difference betweeen two binary files; and sometimes, you want to bypass the heuristics which decide whether or not a file is binary (a file with text in some unknown encoding might trigger the "is a binary" heuristics when it shouldn't, for example).

Comment: My main reason for asking was to see if there was any chance of either missing a potential difference or generating a false positive for differences when processing binaries. I value data integrity over how much output information is given.

Comment: To my understanding, the option strictly controls how differences are reported, not how they are detected. For many scenarios, it is more economical to replace a binary file with another rather than communicate their difference, whereas the opposite tends to hold for different versions of the same textual data.